# Como exibir uma lista vindo de um sub-array Json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, each

Estou construindo divs dinamicamente via Javascript. Quero fazer com que o conteúdo dela exiba algumas informações (nome de usuários, emails, etc). Os dados estão vindo do Banco de Dados em formato Json.

O problema é que ele não exibe todos os participantes. Exibe apenas o primeiro...

Estou montando dessa forma:

```
$.each(value.participantes, function (index, item){
    console.log(item);       
    html+= '<div id="infoUser" class="hide infoUser">'
            + '<div class="pull-left">'
            +   '<img src="/resources/img/teste.jpg" class="foto-info-usuario" />'
            + '</div>'
            + '<div class="pull-right">'
            +   '<div>'
            +       '<i id="close" class="fa fa-times fa-lg pull-right closePopover"></i>'
            +   '</div>'
            +   '<div class="informacoes-user-texto">'
            +       '<label class="nomeUser">'+item.nome_usuario+'</label>'
            +   '<div class="fone-user">'
            +       '<i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> '+item.fone_com+''
            +   '</div>'
            +   '<div class="email-user">'
            +       '<i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> '+item.login+''
            +   '</div>'
            +   '<div class="lista-tags wrap">'
            +       '<div class="tags">'
            +           '<div class="ribbon-top"></div>'
            +           '<div class="ribbon-bottom"></div>'
            +           '<label class="tags-user">Líder</label>'
            +       '</div>'
            +   '</div>'
            + '</div>'
            + '</div>'
            + '</div>';
});
```

O conteúdo do Json é esse (console):

```
Object { nome_usuario="Albson Xavier", id_usuario=1786, login="albson.xavier@grupomoura.com"}

Object { nome_usuario="Bruno Melo Pimentel", arquivo_foto="4.jpg", id_usuario=4, mais...}

Object { nome_usuario="Usuario Indefinido", id_usuario=1574, login="indefinido@grupomoura.com"}

Object { nome_usuario="Albson Xavier", id_usuario=1786, login="albson.xavier@grupomoura.com"}

Object { nome_usuario="Lucinéa Correia", id_usuario=1519, login="lucinea.correia@grupomoura.com"}

Object { nome_usuario="Albson Xavier", id_usuario=1786, login="albson.xavier@grupomoura.com"}

Object { nome_usuario="Mere Magalhães", id_usuario=3, login="mere.magalhaes@grupomoura.com"}

Object { nome_usuario="Albson Xavier", id_usuario=1786, login="albson.xavier@grupomoura.com"}

Object { nome_usuario="Albson Xavier", id_usuario=1786, login="albson.xavier@grupomoura.com"}

Object { nome_usuario="Vilanêz Brayner", arquivo_foto="5.jpg", id_usuario=5, mais...}

Object { nome_usuario="Cledson Lima", id_usuario=1, login="cledsonlima@gmail.com"}

Object { nome_usuario="Marcos Moraes", id_usuario=2, login="marcos.moraes@teste.com"}

Object { nome_usuario="Albson Xavier", id_usuario=1786, login="albson.xavier@grupomoura.com"}

Object { nome_usuario="Anderson Souza", arquivo_foto="teste.jpg", id_usuario=1702, mais...}
```

Comment: Tente remover os "ids" dos elementos HTML. Essa propriedade tem o propósito de ser unica.

Comment: Poderia certificar que 'html' está correto no final do loop? Poderia postar o restante do código?

Comment: Sim sim, já me certifiquei que o html está correto. O problema é que ele não está pegando apenas o primeiro item do array json. Ele não consegue exigir os outros nome dos usuários, por exemplo... entende?

Comment: Tente remover os "ids" dos elementos HTML. Essa propriedade tem o propósito de ser unica

Comment: Fiz isso, mas o problema continua.

Comment: Você consegue fazer um [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) com o seu código pra podermos avaliar o problema? Ou posta a função inteira do .js.

Comment: Como é que você está renderizando a variável 'html' ?

Comment: Pelo JSFiddle fica muito ruim. Melhor postar toda função JS.

Comment: Podes colocar aqui o resultado de `JSON.stringify(value.participantes);`?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/andrealbson/whbzupfd/

Comment: No link acima (jsfiddle), coloquei toda a função JS.

Comment: @AndréAlbson testa assim: https://jsfiddle.net/whbzupfd/1/ funciona?

Comment: Não funcionou. Ocorre o mesmo erro

Comment: @AndréAlbson dá para fazer um jsFiddle com o problema a acontecer ao vivo? senão fica dificil esta pergunta ter resposta e ser útil a mais alguém...

Comment: Fiz o teste do seu código, adicionei alguns itens, e aqui funcionou normalmente: https://jsfiddle.net/eojfqk7u/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizando o HTML da forma abaixo funciona normalmente:

```js
var html = "";
var participantes = [
  {nome_usuario: "Albson Xavier", id_usuario: 1786, login: "albson.xavier@grupomoura.com"},
  {nome_usuario: "Usuario Indefinido", id_usuario: 1574, login: "indefinido@grupomoura.com"}
];

$.each(participantes, function (index, item){
  html+= '<div id="infoUser' + index + '" class="hide infoUser">'
  + '<div class="pull-left">'
  +   '<img src="/resources/img/teste.jpg" class="foto-info-usuario" />'
  + '</div>'
  + '<div class="pull-right">'
  +   '<div>'
  +       '<i id="close' + index + '" class="fa fa-times fa-lg pull-right closePopover"></i>'
  +   '</div>'
  +   '<div class="informacoes-user-texto">'
  +       '<label class="nomeUser">'+item.nome_usuario+'</label>'
  +   '<div class="fone-user">'
  +       '<i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> '+item.fone_com+''
  +   '</div>'
  +   '<div class="email-user">'
  +       '<i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> '+item.login+''
  +   '</div>'
  +   '<div class="lista-tags wrap">'
  +       '<div class="tags">'
  +           '<div class="ribbon-top"></div>'
  +           '<div class="ribbon-bottom"></div>'
  +           '<label class="tags-user">Líder</label>'
  +       '</div>'
  +   '</div>'
  + '</div>'
  + '</div>'
  + '</div>';
});

$("#conteudo").append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="conteudo">
</div>
```

Comment: Aqui não funcionou :(

Comment: Esse mesmo exemplo não funcionou pra você? Qual o seu navegador?

Comment: Uso o Google Chrome

Comment: Clicando no play no exemplo acima não funciona tbm?

Comment: Funcionou sim! Obrigado pela ajuda.